# Come si chiama quello che suona per segnare la fine di una lezione?

Tags: vocabulary, nouns

In Spagna è abituale emettere un suono simile a quello di una sirena per segnare la fine di una lezione. Immagino sia qualcosa simile in Italia, ma come si chiama quello che suona per segnare la fine di una lezione?

Comment: Come si chiama in spagnolo?

Comment: @Josh61: In spagnolo diciamo che "suena el timbre".

Comment: In Italia, ancora nelle stazioni più piccole, è possibile sentire un 'timbre' anche quando sta per arrivare un treno.

Comment: Non so però se questo 'timbre', come per la scuola, si chiami 'campanella'.

Comment: @ElberichSchneider - Sì, si chiama  *campanella* anche quella della stazione ( *leopolder* in termini tecnici). https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100819082602AAhPfIm

Comment: Abbiamo anche un analogo di "saved by the bell" in "salvato dalla campanella" - ma la campanella in questione è quella della boxe, per quanto si possa spesso applicare letteralmente in un contesto scolastico quando è giornata di interrogazioni :)

Comment: Perché adesso un voto negativo? :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Italia si chiama comunemente *la campanella della scuola*.

[La campanella](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=campanella%20della%20scuola) (il suono)

***[Campanella](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/campanella.php):***

> - A scuola, campanello elettrico, un tempo piccola campana che si suonava tirando una cordicella, che scandisce le fasi dell'orario scolastico: *non si entra in classe dopo la campanella.* (Garzanti)
>
>   [Ricomincia la scuola](http://www.wired.it/play/cultura/2014/09/15/scuole-digitalizzazione/):
> - Il suono della campanella è sempre lo stesso. I problemi, purtroppo, anche.

Comment: E quello della porta di una casa è invece "il campanello"?

Comment: Sì, *il campanello di casa* è l'espressione comunemente usata. Es: 'Prima di entrare, suonare sempre il campanello'.