# Usi di "campanello" e di "campanella"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, nouns

In [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5322/707) si sono menzionati alcuni usi dei vocaboli "campanello" e "campanella", che a me sembrano molto curiosi perché corrispondono a una unica parola ("timbre") nella mia lingua (eccetto quando si tratta di una vera piccola campana, allora usiamo il vocabolo "campana"). Ultimamente stavo leggendo il romanzo *Testimone inconsapevole* di Gianrico Carofiglio e ho osservato che là appare un altro uso del termine "campanella": la campanella usata in aula durante un giudizio per avvertire che l'udienza sta per cominciare. Potreste elencarmi i diversi usi di "campanello" e di "campanella"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La campanella è semplicemente una piccola campana, intesa come oggetto/dispositivo. Quella che suona a scuola è (o suppongo fosse in origine) anch'essa una piccola campana, quindi si usa "campanella". In tempi recenti era elettrica, ma il suono era più o meno sempre quello di una campanella. Oggigiorno non so come sia, ma suppongo si chiami ancora "campanella" per tradizione.

Il campanello (maschile) si usa al 90% solo per indicare il "timbre" delle abitazioni o dei condomini (per esempio, quando si va a trovare qualcuno si suona il campanello per avvisare che siamo arrivati e perché ci apra la porta). Il campanello è normalmente elettrico; certe case antiche o di campagna hanno una vera e propria campana come "campanello", quindi in quei casi si dice "suonare la campana".

C'è poi, [informa il Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/campanello/), uno strumento musicale chiamato "campanelli" (plurale), che non conoscevo, che sarebbe il termine italiano per il carillon (lo strumento musicale vero e proprio, non la scatola che riproduce melodie).

Infine c'è un uso idiomatico: "il campanello d'allarme" è ciò che suona (metaforicamente) quando si sospetta o intravede qualche problema, o (realmente) se scatta qualche sistema d'allarme (anche se in molti casi si usano sirene o altri dispositivi).

L'oggetto che suona durante la messa o in tribunale io direi che è una "campanella"; [secondo il Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/campanella/) è sinonimo di "campanello" perlomeno nel significato di "piccola campana", quindi si possono usare entrambe le versioni.

Comment: E quello della bicicletta come si chiama?

Comment: Se ho capito bene quello che c'è nel Treccani, lo strumento musicale si chiama "campanelli" (al plurale) e corrisponde al [carillon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carillon).

Comment: Quello della bici è il campanello, grazie per ricordarmelo.

Comment: Sì esatto, il carillon è anche detto (sempre secondo il Treccani) "campanelli": http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/carillon/. Ignoravo l'esistenza della versione italiana.